# How do I add this field properly?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am working on this bootcamp task that is designed for me to practice inheritance. The base class looks like this:

```
public class Animal {
private int numTeeth = 0;
private boolean spots = false;
private int weight = 0;

public Animal(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight){
    this.setNumTeeth(numTeeth);
    this.setSpots(spots);
    this.setWeight(weight);
}

public int getNumTeeth(){
    return numTeeth;
}

public void setNumTeeth(int numTeeth) {
    this.numTeeth = numTeeth;
}

public boolean getSpots() {
    return spots;
}

public void setSpots(boolean spots) {
    this.spots = spots;
}

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}
```

I am supposed to create a sub class called lion that inherits from the Animal class with the following specific requirements:

1. Add a field for lion t ​ype ( ​ cub, male, female).
2. Add a method in this class which sets the lion type based on its weight (note that the weight is a derived field from the superclass).
3. If the weight is less than 80kg, it’s type should be a cub. If less than
   120kg, it should be female. If greater than 120kg, it is a male.
4. Include a method that will print out a description of a lion object.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours but the best I could come up with is the following:

```
public class Lion extends Animal {
    public Lion(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight) {
        super(numTeeth, spots, weight);
    
        }
        
    void lionDisplay() {
        String type = new String();
        {
        if (getWeight() >= 120) {
            type.equals("Male");
        }   
        else if (getWeight() < 120 && getWeight() >= 80) {
            type.equals("Female");  
        }
        else if (getWeight() < 80) {
            type.equals("Cub");
        }
        System.out.println("Animal = Lion");
        System.out.println("Teeth = " + getNumTeeth());
        System.out.println("Spots = " + getSpots());
        System.out.println("Weight = " + getWeight());
        System.out.println("Type = " + type);
    }
    }
    }
public class AnimalLauncher {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        
        Lion leo = new Lion(30, false, 90);
        leo.lionDisplay();
        
    
    }
}
```

}

I know I am doing something wrong but I don't know what it is. For some reason I cannot get the 'type' to display at all.

This is the output I am getting:

```
Animal = Lion
Teeth = 30
Spots = false
Weight = 90
Type =
```

Comment: Well, you are not giving any value to Type variable anywhere.

Comment: `String type = new String();` just creates an empty `String`. You're not setting it to anything else, are you?

Comment: The two comments above will help you fix the first problem, but also be aware that a 'field' means a variable that's at the top level of the class. You currently have the type defined as a variable in the `lionDisplay()` method, which works fine for your purposes, but the question is asking for a field, which I would interpret as being defined outside the methods. So, I'd put your `String type = new String()` right at the top, after `public class Lion...` and before the constructor (`public Lion(...`)...

Comment: Once you've done that, I'd then set the `type` in the constructor, rather than in the `lionDisplay()` method, because then it will only get set once, rather than setting it again every time you display the lion's details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest adding `type` as a class attribute

```
public class Lion extends Animal {
    private String type;
    
    
    public Lion(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight) {
        super(numTeeth, spots, weight);
        this.type =  type;
    }
```

Add a setter method to change the value

```
public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
```

And in the `lionDisplay` method

```
void lionDisplay() {
       
       
            if (getWeight() >= 120) {
                setType("Male");
            }
            else if (getWeight() < 120 && getWeight() >= 80) {
                setType("Female");
            }
            else if (getWeight() < 80) {
                setType("Cub");
            }
            System.out.println("Animal = Lion");
            System.out.println("Teeth = " + getNumTeeth());
            System.out.println("Spots = " + getSpots());
            System.out.println("Weight = " + getWeight());
            System.out.println("Type = " + type);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest misconception you seem to have here is the `equals` method, which in fact is a method used to compare two instances and returns whether they are equal or not. This method is not used to set a variable, the only way to do that is using the `=` operator (or calling a method that does this for you).

So all you're ending up doing is checking `new String()` (which should generally be initialised as `""`) against various other strings, which obviously always returns false, and then moving on. With your code what you should be doing is something like this:

```
String type = "";

if (getWeight() >= 120) {
    type = "Male";
}
else if (getWeight() < 120 && getWeight() >= 80) {
    type = "Female";
}
else if (getWeight() < 80) {
    type = "Cub"'
}
```

---

Now this would fix your problem, but the practice question actually asks you to add a field for the lion type, in which I presume they mean a class member, so a top level variable that belongs to the class state. Something like:

```
public class Lion extends Animal {
    
    String type = "Unknown";
}
```

However it also asks you to set this based upon the animals weight, which is known during construction via the superclass `Animal`. Therefore this field should be initialised during the construction phase, something like:

```
String type;

public Lion(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight) {

    super(numTeeth, spots, weight);

    if (weight >= 120) {
        type = "Male";
    }
    else if (weight >= 80) {
        type = "Female";
    }
    else {
        type = "Cub";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a field to `Lion`:

```
private String type;
```

Add a getter for it.

Add `String type` to Lion’s constructor, which should call Animal’s constructor, then assign `type`:

```
public Lion(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight, String type) {
    super(numTeeth, spots, weight);
    this.type =  type;
}
```

Then:

```
System.out.println("Type = " + getType());
```

—--

It is good practice to make all fields `final` and delete all setter methods - [Immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Also, `Animal` should be an `abstract` class.